# How to test that typescript declaration files compile against local js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've added typescript definitions to [HunterLarco/twitter-v2](https://github.com/HunterLarco/twitter-v2) which has the structure:

```
package.json
src/
  twitter.js
  twitter.d.ts
  Credentials.js
  Credentials.d.ts
```

and I'd like to test that `.js` files match the `.d.ts` declaration files.

#### Current Progress

Right now I'm using this `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["es2018"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "paths": { "twitter-v2": ["src"] },
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src"
    ],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2018"
  },

  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "tests/**/*"
  ]
}
```

but when I intentionally add incorrect type information to `twitter.d.ts` and run `tsc --project tsconfig.json` it reports no errors and writes to `dist/`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to enable the compiler option to check js files (which typescript does not do by default even with js is allowed)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#checkJs

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node10/tsconfig.json",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },

  "include": ["src/**/*", "tests/**/*"]
}
```